# How to read an IP address backwards?

Tags: shell, text-processing

If we have this string ([IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address)): `192.168.1.1`

How can I derive the ([DNS reverse record form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup)) from this string, so it will be shown like `1.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa` using a shell script?

Comment: It has to be with the shell?

Comment: Stop doing that

Comment: With this amount of answers this should better be in codegolf ;)

Comment: @tkausl, share it there if you want to :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do it with [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK). There are nicer ways to do it, but this is the simplest, I think.

```
echo '192.168.1.1' | awk 'BEGIN{FS="."}{print $4"."$3"."$2"."$1".in-addr.arpa"}'
```

This will reverse the order of the IP address.

Just to save a few keystrokes, as Mikel suggested, we can further shorten the upper statement:

```
echo '192.168.1.1' | awk -F . '{print $4"."$3"."$2"."$1".in-addr.arpa"}'
```

OR

```
echo '192.168.1.1' | awk -F. '{print $4"."$3"."$2"."$1".in-addr.arpa"}'
```

OR

```
echo '192.168.1.1' | awk -F. -vOFS=. '{print $4,$3,$2,$1,"in-addr.arpa"}'
```

AWK is pretty flexible. :)

Comment: If you want to save a few keystrokes, `-F .` should be equivalent to `BEGIN{FS="."}`.

Answer (score 34):

*Just for curiosity value...* using `tac` from GNU coreutils: given a variable `ip` in the form `192.168.1.1` then

```
$(printf %s "$ip." | tac -s.)in-addr.arpa
```

i.e.

```
$ ip=192.168.1.1
$ rr=$(printf %s "$ip." | tac -s.)in-addr.arpa
$ echo "$rr"
1.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa
```

Comment: +1 This is definitely my favorite answer here. Thanks for introducing me to `tac`!

Comment: Thanks are also due to @StéphaneChazelas for the elegant `printf` edit (I originally posted an ugly `echo -n`)

Comment: Clearly simpler: `printf 'arpa.in-addr.%s.' "$ip" | tac -s.`

Answer (score 18):

If you want to use only shell (`zsh`, `ksh93`, `bash`), here's another way:

```
IFS=. read w x y z <<<'192.168.1.1'
printf '%d.%d.%d.%d.in-addr.arpa.' "$z" "$y" "$x" "$w"
```

Or in plain old shell:

```
echo '192.168.1.1' | { IFS=. read w x y z; echo "$z.$y.$w.$x.in-addr.arpa."; }
```

Answer (score 13):

Easily with Perl, thusly:

```
$ echo 192.168.1.1|perl -nle 'print join ".",reverse(split /\./,$_)'
1.1.168.192
```

Comment: Can be made even more compact: `perl -F'\.' -lane '$,=".";print reverse @F'`

Answer (score 7):

To round it out, Ruby:

```
ruby -r ipaddr -e 'puts IPAddr.new(ARGV.first).reverse' 192.168.1.1
```

Which also supports IPv6

```
2607:F8B0:4000:080A:0000:0000:0000:2000
=> 0.0.0.2.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.a.0.8.0.0.0.0.4.0.b.8.f.7.0.6.2.ip6.arpa
```

Comment: you could take the "require" out of the script: `ruby -r ipaddr -e 'puts ...'`

Comment: I think the OP needs shell..

Answer (score 6):

Through GNU `sed`,

```
sed -r 's/^([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3})$/\4.\3.\2.\1.in-addr.arpa/g' file
```

It reverses any IPv4-address format.

**Example:**

```
$ echo '192.168.1.1' | sed -r 's/^([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3})$/\4.\3.\2.\1.in-addr.arpa/g'
1.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa

$ echo '192.1.1.1' | sed -r 's/^([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3})$/\4.\3.\2.\1.in-addr.arpa/g'
1.1.1.192.in-addr.arpa

$ echo '1.1.1.1' | sed -r 's/^([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3})$/\4.\3.\2.\1.in-addr.arpa/g'
1.1.1.1.in-addr.arpa

$ sed -r 's/^([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3})$/\4.\3.\2.\1.in-addr.arpa/g' <<< '192.168.189.23'
23.189.168.192.in-addr.arpa
```

Comment: This is the fastest solution! 45k IPs converted in just 0.794s.

Answer (score 5):

With `zsh`:

```
$ ip=192.168.1.1
$ echo ${(j:.:)${(s:.:Oa)ip}}.in-addr.arpa
1.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa
```

Those are variable expansion flags:

- `s:.:`: **s**plit on `.`
- `Oa`: reverse **o**rder the **a**rray
- `j:.:`: **j**oin on `.`

Answer (score 4):

Using Python’s [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Address.reverse_pointer):

```
>>> ipaddress.ip_address('192.168.1.1').reverse_pointer
'1.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa'
```

Comment: This is in the 3.5 standard library and scheduled to be released September 2015. From a script you can do: `python3.5 -c "import ipaddress; ipaddress.ip_address('192.168.1.1').reverse_pointer"` (all on one line)

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to use the "dig" command line tool with the "-x" switch.

It actually does a request on the PTR entry, but if you filter on "PTR" it will show you one commented line (the request) and maybe some replies.

Using "dig" can be handy for a quick writing of the PTR name, without having to write a small script. Particularly if you need it interactively (to cut and paste the result).
It works on IPv6 too.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it working with **IPv6** as well, you can use `dig -x`.

For example:

```
$ dig -x 194.68.208.240 | egrep '^;.*PTR$' | cut -c 2- | awk '{print $1}'
240.208.68.194.in-addr.arpa.

$ dig -x 2001:db8:dc61:2a61::1 | egrep '^;.*PTR$' | cut -c 2- | awk '{print $1}'
1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.1.6.a.2.1.6.c.d.8.b.d.0.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa.
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python

```
 a = "192.168.1.122"
 import re
 m = re.search(r'(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)',a)
 ip = m.group(4),m.group(3),m.group(2),m.group(1)
 '.'.join(ip) + ".in-addr.arpa"
 '122.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa'
```

Comment: Or more idiomatically, `"{}.in-addr.arpa".format(".".join(reversed(a.split("."))))` in Python2.7

Answer (score 2):

```
IFS=. ; set -- ${0+192.168.1.2}
printf %b. $4 $3 $2 $1 in-addr.arpa\\c

IFS=. ; printf %s\\n \
    in-addr.arpa ${0+192.168.1.2} |    
sed '1!G;$s/\n/./gp;h;d'

IFS=. ; printf '[%b.] ' \
    ${0+192.168.1.2.]PPPPP\\c} |dc
echo in-addr.arpa
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ while read ip
while> do
while> n=( $(echo $ip) ) && echo "${n[4]}"'.'"${n[3]}"'.'"${n[2]}"'.'"${n[1]}"'.'"in-addr.arpa"
while> done
192.168.1.2
2.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa
```

This way you can type in an address and hit return for your result.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a var contains the ip: `ip=192.168.2.1`. If the value needs to be given to a new variable, just enclose any solution inside `$()` and assign that to the var `rr=$(...)`.

Some solutions are possible:

Simplest     `:         printf 'arpa.in-addr.%s.' "$ip" | tac -s.`
Most shells`:       IFS=. eval 'set -- $ip'; echo "$4.$3.$2.$1.in-addr.arpa"`
Some shells  `:     IFS=. read d c b a <<<"$ip";  printf %s "$a.$b.$c.$d.in-addr.arpa."`
[awk](/questions/tagged/awk)  `:           echo "$ip" | awk -F. '{OFS=FS;print $4,$3,$2,$1,"in-addr.arpa"}'`
[sed](/questions/tagged/sed)  `:           echo "$ip" | sed -E 's/([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)$/\4.\3.\2.\1.in-addr.arpa./'`
[sed](/questions/tagged/sed)  `:           echo "arpa.in-addr.$ip" | sed 'y/./\n/' | sed 'G;$s/\n/./gp;h;d'`
[perl](/questions/tagged/perl) `:           echo "$ip" | perl -F\\. -lane '$,=".";print( join(".",(reverse @F),"in-addr.arpa"))'`
[dig](/questions/tagged/dig) `:            dig -x "$ip" | awk -F '[; \t]+' '/^;.*PTR$/{print($2)}'`
[host](/questions/tagged/host)`:            host -t ptr 192.168.2.1 | cut -d' ' -f2`

Both dig and host solutions work with IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
# script file name reverseip.sh
if [ -z $1 ] || [ "help" == $1 ]
then
echo 'Convert a full ipv4 or ipv6 address to arpa notation'
echo "usage:"
echo ./reverseip.sh "help"
echo ./reverseip.sh "ipv4 address format: xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx"
echo ./reverseip.sh "ipv6 address format: xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::xxxx"
echo "examples:"
echo ./reverseip.sh 216.58.207.35
echo ./reverseip.sh 2a00:1450:4001:824::2003
exit
fi

# if ip address passed containing ':'
if [[ $1 = *':'* ]];
then
# invert ipv6 address e.g.: 2a00:1450:4001:824::2003 to 3.0.0.2.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.4.2.8.0.1.0.0.4.0.5.4.1.0.0.a.2.
# @see lsowen https://gist.github.com/lsowen/4447d916fd19cbb7fce4
echo "$1" | awk -F: 'BEGIN {OFS=""; }{addCount = 9 - NF; for(i=1; i<=NF;i++){if(length($i) == 0){ for(j=1;j<=addCount;j++){$i = ($i "0000");} } else { $i = substr(("0000" $i), length($i)+5-4);}}; print}' | rev | sed -e "s/./&./g" | echo "$(</dev/stdin)ip6.arpa."
else
# invert ipv6 address e.g.: 216.58.207.35 to 35.207.58.216.in-addr.arpa
# @see Stéphane Chazelas https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132779/how-to-read-an-ip-address-backwards
echo $(printf %s "$1." | tac -s.)in-addr.arpa
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

With `host` command from `dnsutils`:

```
$ host -t ptr 192.168.1.1 | cut -d' ' -f 2
1.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
```

Comment: This only works for addresses you can lookup in your DNS. If you try an unknown address you will get an error message (which however includes the reverse address but need slightly different postprocessing).

Answer (score 0):

A shorter alternative to [mattbianco's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/134611/253946) with less tools, but using [pcregrep](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcregrep.html) could be:

```
$ dig -x 194.68.208.240 | pcregrep -o1 '^;(\S+)\s+IN\s+PTR$'
240.208.68.194.in-addr.arpa.

$ dig -x 2001:db8:dc61:2a61::1 | pcregrep -o1 '^;(\S+)\s+IN\s+PTR$'
1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.1.6.a.2.1.6.c.d.8.b.d.0.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following one line shell:

```
echo '192.168.1.1' | tr '.' '\n' | tac | paste -s -d '.' -
```

Answer (score 0):

Using POSIX `sh`:

```
$ ip=192.168.1.1
$ rev_ip=`
      IFS=.
      set -- $ip    # set positional parameters: $1, $2, $3, ...
      echo $4.$3.$2.$1.in-addr.arpa
  `
$ echo $rev_ip
1.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa
```

**Note**: Be careful when setting `IFS`. In my example, I isolated the internal field separator (IFS) in a subshell using the backtick operator, otherwise you may have to reset/restore it.

Alternatively, you could avoid `IFS` and use `tr` instead:

```
$ set -- `echo $ip | tr . \ `
$ echo $4.$3.$2.$1.in-addr.arpa
```

If you're using `ksh` or `bash`, use the `$( )` subshell operator instead.

Comment: `$( ... )` is to be preferred over backticks