# How can I reverse the first part of a sentence?

Tags: shell

I know that I can reverse any sentence:
`echo "a,b,c,d" | rev`

but what if I want to reverse only the first part of a sentence, I have tried this:

`echo "a,b,c,d Access" | rev`

and I get this:

`sseccA d,c,b,a`, and what I really want is:

`d,c,b,a Access`

How can I do this?

Comment: There are a lot of useful answers that will help you in this question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132779/how-to-read-an-ip-address-backwards

Comment: @Networker, Thanks but the answers add a string ".in-addr.arpa" at the end, here I'm already have the string "Access"

Comment: So the problem is: given `$1 $2 $3...$n`, print `(rev $1) $2 $3...$n`?

Comment: @Mikel, yes this is it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to use `read` to break the line into the first word and the rest, then call `rev` on only the first word

```
$ echo "a,b,c,d Access" | { read -r first rest; printf '%s %s\n' "$(rev <<< "$first")" "$rest"; }
d,c,b,a Access
```

Comment: That assumes the input doesn't contain backslash characters and `$first` doesn't start with `-`.

Comment: Yeah, we can use `read -r` and `printf '%s` if necessary.

Comment: Then why don't we? Why promote a broken command like `echo`?

Comment: Done, but untested (not at my computer).

Answer (score 4):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/^/ /;:1
     s/^\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]\)/\2\1 /;t1
     s/ //'
```

With `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/\S+/reverse $&/e'
```

With `zsh`:

```
string='a,b,c,d Access'
setopt extendedglob
result=${string/(#m)[^ ]#/${(j::)${(Oas::)MATCH}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `pee` (pipe tee) from [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) (`apt-get install moreutils`):

`echo -n "a,b,c,d Access" | pee "cut -d ' ' -f 1 | rev" "cut -d ' ' -f 2" | tr '\n' ' '`

The result is `d,c,b,a Access` with a trailing space, which comes from a translated newline.

Comment: `bash: pee: command not found`

Comment: Try `apt-get install moreutils` on Debian/Ubuntu or the equivalent on your Linux.

Comment: I have install pee and have tried the command but it failed:
a,b,c,d Access

Comment: @user79550 Hmm... It works for me - but I had left out the `rev` in the first version I saved, edited shortly after. Can you check the `rev` is there?

Comment: Upvoted because it works for the original question, but take note that it doesn't work for multiple fields (words).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on [Neven answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132779/how-to-read-an-ip-address-backwards?answertab=votes#tab-top):

You can do this using this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
secondPart=`echo "a,b,c,d Access" | awk '{print $2} '`
firstPart=`echo "a,b,c,d Access" | awk '{print $1} '| awk -F , '{print $4","$3","$2","$1""}'`
echo "$firstPart $secondPart"
```

in command line just type:

```
sh yourShellscript.sh
```

or using one command line as [Jidder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/78605/jidder) suggeted:

```
awk '$1=gensub(/(.),(.),(.),(.)/,"\\4,\\3,\\2,\\1","g",$1)' <<< "a,b,c,d Access"
```

Comment: Thanks but can I do it using one command line

Comment: @user79550 awk `awk '$1=gensub(/(.),(.),(.),(.)/,"\\4,\\3,\\2,\\1","g",$1)' <<<  "a,b,c,d Access"`

Answer (score 1):

A `perl` solution:

```
$ echo "a,b,c,d Access" | perl -anle 'print ~~reverse($F[0])," @F[1..$#F]"'
d,c,b,a Access
```

Answer (score 1):

Fair warning: this relies on your commas.

```
echo "a,b,c,d Access" | tr ,\  '[\n*]' | 
sed '1!G;$s/\n/,/g;s/\([^,]*\),\(.*\)/\2 \1/p;h;d'
```

#### OUTPUT

```
d,c,b,a Access
```

It's kinda long - longer than it needs to be. It's easier this way:

```
set -f ; IFS=,\                                                                 
set -- ${0+a,b,c,d Access}
while [ -n "${2+?}" ]
do  r="$1,$r" 
shift ; done    
echo "${r%,} $1"
```

#### OUTPUT

```
d,c,b,a Access
```

Still kinda long, but at least it makes sense. It get's a little easier with a function because you get a shell array. Like:

```
rev() ( i=
    set -f ; IFS=$1 ; shift ; set -- $*
    until [ "$((i=${i:=($#+1)}-1))" -eq 0 ]
    do  [ "$i" -gt 1 ] && s=$IFS || s=                                          
        eval printf '"%s$s"' \""\$$i"\"
    done
)
rev , a,b,c,d && echo \ Access
```

#### OUTPUT

```
d,c,b,a Access
```

Or if you have it in a variable:

```
var="a,b,c,d Access"
rev , "${var% *}" && echo " ${var##* }"
```

#### OUTPUT

```
d,c,b,a Access
```