# Reversing a variable's contents by words

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variable

So if I've got a variable

```
VAR='10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100'
```

and echo it out

```
echo "$VAR"
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
```

However, further down the script I need to reverse the order of this variable so it shows as something like

```
echo "$VAR" | <code to reverse it>
100 90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10
```

I tried using rev and it literally reversed everything so it came out as

```
echo "$VAR" | rev
001 09 08 07 06 05 04 03 02 01
```

Comment: You may find some useful suggestions in answers to this similar question: [How to read an IP address backwards?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132779/how-to-read-an-ip-address-backwards/) (just need to adjust for space separators in place of the periods)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

On GNU systems, the reverse of cat is tac:

```
$ tac -s" " <<< "$VAR "            # Please note the added final space.
100 90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10
```

Comment: Cheers! That did the trick. I've still got a lot to learn

Comment: @JhonKugelman Without the echo, the output has an additional newline, equivalent to this: `echo $'100 \n90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10'`

Comment: With the current `tac -s" " <<< "$VAR "` version, it still inserts a leading blank line, adds a trailing space and omits the trailing newline character (as if `printf '\n%s ' "$reversed_VAR"` instead of expected `printf '%s\n' "$reversed_VAR"`)

Comment: @don_crissti The original answer: `echo $(tac -s" " <<< $VAR)` does not have a trailing space because the `$(…)` removes trailing newlines and spaces if the IFS has them. My solution will be corrected soon, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

For a short list, and in a variable, the shell itself is the fastest solution:

```
var="10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100"
set -- $var; unset a 
for ((i=$#;i>0;i--)); do
    printf '%s%s' "${a:+ }" "${!i}"
    a=1
done
echo
```

Output:

```
100 90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10
```

Note: the split operation in `set -- $var` is safe for the exact string used here, but will not be so if the string contains wildcard characters (`*`, `?` or `[]`). It may be avoided with `set -f` before the split, if needed.
The same note is also valid for the following solutions (except where noted).

Or, if you want to set some other variable with the reverse list:

```
var="10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100"
set -- $var
for i; do out="$i${out:+ }$out"; done
echo "$out"
```

Or using only the positional parameters.

```
var="10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100"
set -- $var
a=''
for    i
do     set -- "$i${a:+ $@}"
       a=1
done
echo "$1"
```

Or using only one variable (which may be var itself):
Note: This solution is not affected by globing nor IFS.

```
var="10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100"

a=" $var"
while [[ $a ]]; do
    printf '<%s>' "${a##* }"
    var="${a% *}"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue

```
$ var='10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100'

$ echo "$var" | awk '{for(i=NF; i>0; i--) printf i==1 ? $i"\n" : $i" "}'
100 90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10
```

with `perl`, courtesy [How to read an IP address backwards?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132779/how-to-read-an-ip-address-backwards/) shared by @steeldriver

```
$ echo "$var" | perl -lane '$,=" "; print reverse @F'
100 90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10
```

Or, with `bash` itself by converting the string to array

```
$ arr=($var)    
$ for ((i=${#arr[@]}-1; i>=0; i--)); do printf "${arr[i]} "; done; echo
100 90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use bash features such as arrays to do it entirely in-process:

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR="10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100"
a=($VAR); rev_a=()
for ((i=${#a[@]}-1;i>=0;i--)); do rev_a+=( ${a[$i]} ); done; 
RVAR=${rev_a[*]};
```

This should be about the fastest way to do it provided that $VAR isn't very very large.

Comment: That however doesn't extend to variables whose value contains wildcard characters (like `VAR='+ * ?'`). Use `set -o noglob` or `set -f` to fix that. More generally, it's a good idea to consider the value of `$IFS` and the state of globbing when using the split+glob operator. No that it makes little sense to use that operator in `rev_a+=( ${a[$i]} )`, `rev_a+=( "${a[$i]}" )` would make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 2):

`zsh`:

```
print -r -- ${(Oa)=VAR}
```

`$=VAR` splits `$VAR` on `$IFS`. `(Oa)` orders the resulting list in reverse array order. `print -r --` (like in `ksh`), same as `echo -E -` (`zsh` specific) is [a reliable versions of `echo`](/a/65819): prints its arguments as-is separated by space, terminated by newline.

If you want to split on space only, and not on whatever `$IFS` contains (space, tab, newline, nul by default), either assign space  to `$IFS`, or use an explicit splitting like:

```
print -r -- ${(Oas: :)VAR}
```

To sort in reverse numerical order:

```
$ VAR='50 10 20 90 100 30 60 40 70 80'
$ print -r -- ${(nOn)=VAR}
100 90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10
```

POSIXly (so would also work with `bash`):

With shell builtin (except for `printf` in some shells) mechanisms only (better for variables with a short value):

```
unset -v IFS # restore IFS to its default value of spc, tab, nl
set -o noglob # disable glob
set -- $VAR # use the split+glob operator to assign the words to $1, $2...

reversed_VAR= sep=
for i do
  reversed_VAR=$i$sep$reversed_VAR
  sep=' '
done
printf '%s\n' "$reversed_VAR"
```

With `awk` (better for large variables, especially with `bash`, but up to the limit of the size of the arguments (or of a single argument)):

```
 awk '
   BEGIN {
     n = split(ARGV[1], a);
     while (n) {printf "%s", sep a[n--]; sep = " "}
     print ""
   }' "$VAR"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
printf "%s\n" $var | tac | paste -sd' '
100 90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a bit of Python magic here:

```
bash-4.3$ VAR='10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100'
bash-4.3$ python -c 'import sys;print " ".join(sys.argv[1].split()[::-1])'  "$VAR" 
100 90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10
```

The way this works is fairly simple:

- we refer to `"$VAR"` as  second command line paramenter `sys.argv[1]` ( first parameter with `-c` option is always just that - `-c` itself. Notice the quoting around `"$VAR"` to prevent splitting the variable itself into individual words ( which hisi done by shell , not python )
- Next we use `.split()` method, to break it into a list of strings
- `[::-1]` part is just [extended slice syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.3.html#extended-slices)  to get  reverse of the list
- finally we join everything together back into one string with `" ".join()` and print out

---

But those who aren't big Python fans, we could use `AWK` to do essentially same thing: split, and print array in reverse:

```
 echo "$VAR" | awk '{split($0,a);x=length(a);while(x>-1){printf "%s ",a[x];x--};print ""}'
100 90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10
```

Comment: or somewhat cleaner `python3 -c 'import sys;print(*reversed(sys.argv[1:]))'  $VAR`

Comment: @iruvar, not _cleaner_, that would invoke the shell's split+glob operator without making sure `$IFS` contains the proper characters and without disabling the glob part.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, true enough - the python portion is still cleaner(IMHO) though. So, going back to `"$VAR"` yields `python3 -c 'import sys;print(*reversed(sys.argv[1].split()))'  "$VAR"`

Answer (score 0):

Inelegant *POSIX* software tools one-liner:

```
echo `echo $VAR | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -nr`
```