# Bash, cut off IP from string separated by dots

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut

I've multiple results in the format

```
10.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa name hostname
```

I want to remove the middle part ".in-addr.arpa" and reverse the IP address to, for example, 1.2.3.10. Is that possible with a simple bash one liner? Thanks in advance, I'm trying to do this since hours and kinda stuck.

Comment: How do you define "the middle part"? Will there always be a string of 4 digits separated by `.` and then a non-digit? Can there be numbers in the "middle part"? What kind of reversing do you need exactly? Should it be `1.2.3.10` as in your example or `1.2.3.01`? Finally, what do you mean by "bash one-liner"? I am guessing you don't actually want to do this in bash, you just want a commandline solution, right? You're OK with tools like sed, awk, perl etc? I know you tagged the question with these tags, but since you also ask for a "bash" one-liner, I wanted to clarify.

Comment: For the second part of your question, you may find the following useful: [How to read an IP address backwards?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132779/how-to-read-an-ip-address-backwards)

Comment: Hi, the middle part is always the same constant value ".in-addr.arpa", I want to remove this. It will display everytime. And with reverse IP, a few examples:

10.11.12.13 --> would be --> 13.12.11.10
10.09.08.07 --> would be --> 07.08.09.10
and so on.
I just want a commandline solution, thank you in advance

Comment: Great. Please [edit] your question to include this. Especially the part about simply needing to remove the same string from all lines. That makes everything much much easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `perl`:

```bsh
perl -pe 's/(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.in-addr\.arpa/$4.$3.$2.$1/g' < input
```

Which is a bit less verbose and a bit more legible than the standard `sed` equivalent:

```bsh
d='\([0-9]\{1,\}\)'
LC_ALL=C sed "s/$d\.$d\.$d\.$d\.in-addr\.arpa/\4.\3.\2.\1/g" < input
```

Those replace all occurrences of `<d1>.<d2>.<d3>.<d4>.in-addr.arpa` with `<d4>.<d3>.<d2>.<d1>` (where `<dX>` is any sequence of one or more decimal digits) leaving everything else untouched.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! This looks pretty nice. When I try this, I get "bash: input: no such file or directory". Sorry, do I do something wrong ??

Comment: @user445527, `input` here is a placeholder for the name of the input file that contains the text to process.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ awk '{split($1,p,"."); $1=p[4]"."p[3]"."p[2]"."p[1]} 1' file
1.2.3.10 name hostname
```

Comment: wow, thank you !!! That does work really well. May I ask how I keep the last part "name hostname" just as it is? I want the hostnames of the IPs :) thank you

Comment: I edited my answer to do that but please edit your question to show exactly the output you expect so we aren't guessing.

Answer (score 2):

Another perl approach:

```
$ perl -lane '@ip=split(/\./,$F[0]); $F[0]=join(".",reverse(@ip[0..3])); print "@F"' file
1.2.3.10 name hostname
```

Note that this assumes the first 4 `.`-separated elements of the line are the IP address.

#### Explanation

- `-lane`: the `-a` makes `perl` work like `awk`, splitting each line of input on whitespace and saving the result in the array `@F`. The `-l` adds a newline to each `print` call (and removes trailing newlines from input lines), the `-n` means "read the input line by line and apply the script given by `-e` to each line".
- `@ip=split(/\./,$F[0])`: take the first field (`$F[0]`) and split it on `.`, saving the output in the array `@ip`.
- `$F[0]=join(".",reverse(@ip[0..3]));`: this has a few parts. First, `join(CHAR, ARRAY)` will use the character CHAR to join the elements of ARRAY into a string. Here, we are passing the first 4 elements (indices 0 through 3) of the `@ip` array, so everything until the non-numbers in your example, so the join will produce the IP. Next, the `reverse` reverses it. Finally, we save the result as `$F[0]`.
- `print "@F"` : after the previous steps, the `@F` array now contains what we want, so we print it.

---

If all you want is to remove the first occurrence of the string `.in-addr.arpa` from all lines of your input file and then reverse the IP, you could just do:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\.in-addr\.arpa//; s/(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/$4.$3.$2.$1/' file
1.2.3.10 name hostname
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipe your multiple results to the standard input of this script:

```
while read ip n hn
do
  ip="$(awk -F. '{print $4 "." $3 "." $2 "." $1}' <<< "$ip")"
  printf '%s %s %s\n' "$ip" "$n" "$hn"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to harness the in built looping/sweeping across a string in a regex We setup a backtracking within the regex and stop when it backtracks to the beginning.

```
$ perl -lne '
    m/(.*) ((?<!\d)\d+\.) (?{printf q(%s), $1?$2:$2=~s|\.||r}) (?(?{$1 ne ""}) (?!))/x;
    print /(\s\S.*)/;
' file
1.2.3.10 name hostname
```